# Angular directives update on ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I would like my ngDirective to be updated each time my ng-repeat is updated.
My code looks like:

```
<div ng-cotroller="SomeCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="i in data" myDirective>
        {{i}}
    </div>
</div>



App.controller("SomeCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.data = [1, 2, 3];
});

App.directive("myDirective", function() {
    $(this).sortable({ // how I can get the element?
        start: function(event, ui) {
            ...
        },
        stop: function(event, ui) {
            ...
        }
    });
});
```

**Questions**

- How I use as `$(this)` the element with the directive?
- How I can execute this directive each time the value of `$scope.data` changes a.k.a. ng-repeat is execute?

Thanks.

Comment: How exactly are you changing the values in $scope.data? From my experience with Angular, you would just need to make sure `$scope.data` has the new data and will already show the changes. A very simplistic idea http://jsfiddle.net/L5bdg/1/

Comment: Can you please explain us what is the purpose of ngDirective?

Comment: sortable is usually called on the parent container that holds the items. It's not clear what your issue is. Please create a demo in plunker that replicates your problem. Also you should be using `link` to access element and run the sortable code

Comment: I want each time the ng-repeat is rerendered to execute the jquery sortable. For example my service update $scope.data, ng-repeat renders the changes and my directive is reexecute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, directive accepts min. three parameters, scope, element, and attrs

```
function(scope, element, attrs) {....}
```

Thus, your $(this) is equal to element, or $(element[0])

Second, It's better to use angularJS directive made on that purpose.

For sortable, please use this, https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-sortable.

I am not a big fan of using JQuery in AngularJS because it manipulate DOM without the framework knowing it.

However it is ok to use it as long as it is properly wrapped as a directive if there is no pure angularjs directive out there for certain puropose.